# How do I figure out hotelId for any hotel?

Tags: amadeus

I am trying to get hotel specific details using the following api:

/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel

how do I figure out the hotelId parameter? For example I want to use the aforementioned api, to get information about Pendry San Diego hotel, what would be the hotelId for this hotel.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you are looking for the hotelID from where ? from what ?

What's the API you are talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Hotel Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/hotel/api-doc/hotel-search/api-reference) comes with 3 different endpoints:

1. Get the list of hotels for a specific location.
2. Get the hotel and rooms information for a specific hotel (by its hotel id).
3. Confirm the price and availability before booking.

To get the hotel id, you need to use the first endpoint to find the list of hotels for a given location, then you can use this hotel id with the second endpoint.

As of today, you cannot directly search by a hotel name to get a hotel id. We have this in our backlog but not a specific delivery date yet.

FYI, I searched for hotels in San Diego and retrieved the hotel with the name `Pendry San Diego`:

```
"hotelId": "MNSANPSH",
"name": "Pendry San Diego LVX"
```

Comment: Hi Anthony,

Tried out the /shopping/hotel-offers, 

(https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers?cityCode=SAN&roomQuantity=1&adults=2&radius=20&radiusUnit=MILE&paymentPolicy=NONE&includeClosed=false&bestRateOnly=true&view=FULL&sort=NONE)

I am getting back a list of hotel data, but I am not seeing a lot of the hotels that I am expecting to see in that list, for example Pendry San Diego, Solamar San Diego, etc. Is there anything that I am missing? Is this because I am querying the test environment that's why getting back limited data?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, the test environment is free of charge but limited (in terms of data and in the number of API calls you can do per month). https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/test-environment-data-collection-746

Comment: Thanks Man. This is very helpful.